# CSS File doesn't get loaded

Tags: html, css, nginx, loading

I have the following file, head.inc.php which I include in other files:

```
<?php
    include 'database.inc.php';
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "dani");
    define("DB_PASS", "Reichenschwand5");
    define("DB_NAME", "cocktails");
    $database = new Database();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

The First File from Github gets loaded properly and I can see changes when I enable/disable the import, but the second file doesn't get loaded at all.

When I use View Source in Chrome and click on the style.css it's opened in the browser, so I think the link-tag is correctly formed.

My 2nd guess was that there is a problem with the permissions in Linux, but the permissions on all files in the root-dir are 775 and owned by http:http, in `htop` I can see the user root for a parent process and http as child process for nginx, as well es php-fpm, so there should also be no problem.

My 3rd guess was that there is a problem with the nginx configuration file and included the file `mime.types`, but still no change, also the normalize.css from github works which means the problem shouldn't be there.

Then I created a public repo on my github account and created the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielr1996/css/master/style.css in it and included it. It didn't work either, but I think there might be problem with the accessibility of the repo.

I also tried to include a picture with the `<img>` tag and javascript with `<script>`, which both worked fine.

Eventually I included the css directly with the `<style>` tag, which worked.

Do you know what else could be the problem?

Comment: In Chrome's debug tools, click on the network tab and then refresh your page.  You can then see all of the files (including style.css) which are being passed down from the server.  Inspect this file to see if it has the css you expect it to have. This should provide some direction on where the problem lies.

Comment: Also consider linking using the full URL rather than relative.

Comment: You also need to close your link tags: `<link rel="" />` Your browser might get confused because it thinks the second link tag is part of the body of the first one for some reason.

Comment: Ok, after sitting here for a while browsing StackOverflow I just went back to my site and it worked, so I think it might have been a problem with the cache, but I also tried it with Firefox. However, not it works.@TravisCollins Thanks Anyway, this trick is also useful for other scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the `style.css` file did show in Chrome browser but the css style did not affect any element right?

So, that's mean, the link path is specified correctly. The problem might be that css has been override.

Try to append `!important` after the css attribute to test the effect.

If this working, may be your first stylesheet is override the after.

You can learn this topic more on css override rule.